# Can I let the connection time out but still get the response?

Tags: ruby, timeout

I have a function that gets response over http. It runs some tests. Lately it started to happen that the test never finishes. So I introduced a time out. Then I found out that if I stop the database server the test script finishes with a db error that is in fact very good lead why the test didn't finish as expected. So to get the error could help to save me time. Because I wouldn't have to reproduce the whole test again manually.

Q1: *Is there any way to let the connection time out but then get the response after the database server is restarted?* Note that I cannot send the http request again as it would start the same text again.

Q2: I think that a solution would be to introduce timer while "waiting" for http response. But I don't know how to do that. Any idea?

My function is like

```
def execute_db2_script(url)
  db2_database = 'RATIONAL'
  http_read_timeout=$http_read_timeout
  uri = URI.parse(url)
  start = Time.new

  connection = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, 443)
  connection.use_ssl = true
  begin 
    response = connection.start() do |http|
      http.open_timeout =  50
      http.read_timeout = http_read_timeout
      http.request_get(uri.request_uri)
    end
  rescue Timeout::Error
    time_out_message ="security time out - after #{$http_read_timeout} sec"
  return time_out_message       
  end       
  return response.body.gsub("\n","<BR>")
end
```

Comment: If you [pass a block to `request_get()`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-i-request_get), do you get _any_ response before the timeout?

Comment: If I use the same url in a browser I get nothing until I restart database server. This test holds all other tests so I need to force to finish it. Time out is ok but I want the error message.

Comment: wow, that sounds _broken_. I wouldn't try to fix the test, sounds like the database server or web server handling the request needs to be fixed...

Comment: Yes, it is broken and the test finds it like that. ;-) It doesn't happen always. It stared to happen now and programmers have not fix it so I have to accommodate this in my testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `retry` keyword

```
def execute_db2_script(url)
  ...
  begin 
    ...
  rescue Timeout::Error
    time_out_message ="security time out - after #{$http_read_timeout} sec"
    if "the server is going to restart then"
      retry # this will restart begin-rescue-end block again
    else
      return time_out_message       
    end
  end       

  response.body.gsub("\n","<BR>")
end
```

Comment: Will retry send another http request? It must be the same, I guess. If I use the same url in a browser I get nothing until I restart database server. So I am not sure if retry would work here.

Comment: ha, I'm not a ruby programmer want was going to write a while loop. Retry is awesome. He still might want a fail counter (depending on his code).

Comment: @Radek: A fail counter would be some way for you to only do the `retry` operation three or four times -- and prevent _that_ from also holding up your tests...

Comment: Oh, sounds good. Can I run some code before the 'retry' starts? Hm, but I cannot send another http request it would start the same test again. I need to wait ...

Comment: @Radek, it looks like you don't get an idea of retry, the begin-rescue section executes at first and then the rescue-end section. In last section you can decide what to do next - run the first section again (e.g. using the fail counter or you can sleep for some time) or quit from the method.

Comment: Well that's what I understood and wanted to confirm. So I cannot use `retry`  then.